# Multiple where in clause in Mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

When using the following query Im getting the incorrect results. How can I fix this when working with multiple where in clauses and HAVING.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `otc_employee_qualifications` 
WHERE  `emp_qualifctn_type` 
IN (
'26',  '27'
)
AND  `qualification_value` 
IN (
'62', '64','65'
)
AND  `qualification_mark` >=  '10'
GROUP BY  `employee_id` 
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT  `emp_qualifctn_type` ) =  '2'
AND  COUNT( DISTINCT  `qualification_value` ) =  '3'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

PHPMYADMIN

[image]

Here  I need to get the employee ids who satisfies both the emp_qualifctn_type (27 and 26) and all qualification values in ( '62', '64','65')

Comment: `Where fld1 ... AND fld2 ...`

Comment: Yes. You can't have the word WHERE twice. Use AND instead of the second where as @RavinderReddy says.

Comment: @tyro: You better post some sample records and expected records as output.

Comment: @ Ravinder Reddy I have given the table values

Comment: Please also specify what is that you are trying to query from the table

Comment: @marklong Ive edited the question

Comment: The `HAVING` clause is very strange. I think your problem comes from it. Because the where in is used correctly in your query.

Comment: Something is wrong with your required output from query. Can you explain in words what you want to achieve/retreve from table?

Comment: None of you example test data seems to comply with your requirements. While employee_id 2 and 3 both have both emp_qualifctn_type of 27 and 26, none have all the qualification values of  '62', '64' and '65'. If you only care if they have one of those qualifications values then the 2nd count is not required.

Comment: @Somnath Muluk I want to get all employee_ids say, who have both emp_qualifctn_type  (27 , 29) and both qualification_value (62,50). Here the result would be 2.

Comment: Do rows only count if they match on BOTH checks, or do you count an employee id if lines match on one but not the other, while other lines match on the other but not the one?

Comment: @Kickstart I want employess who satisfies all of the values

Comment: Note that '2' is a string. 2 is an integer. And LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake in the query. I should use 'OR' in the query for combining the multiple cases in HAVING clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM  `otc_employee_qualifications` 
WHERE  `emp_qualifctn_type` IN ('26',  '27')
AND  `qualification_value` IN ('62', '64','65')
AND  `qualification_mark` >=  '10'
GROUP BY  `employee_id` 
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT  `emp_qualifctn_type` ) =  '2'
OR  COUNT( DISTINCT  `qualification_value` ) =  '3'
```

Here the result will be Null which is true.

Answer (score 0):

For your updated comment `I want to get all employee_ids say, who have both emp_qualifctn_type (27 , 29) and both qualification_value (62,50). Here the result would be 2.`. Check this =>

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `otc_employee_qualifications` 
WHERE  `emp_qualifctn_type` 
IN (27,  29)
AND  `qualification_value` 
IN (62, 50)
AND  `qualification_mark` >=  10
GROUP BY  `employee_id`
HAVING count(DISTINCT emp_qualifctn_type) >= 2 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This will give the employee_ids who have either emp_qualifctn_type in (27 ) or (29)  and not those who have both the values.

Comment: @tyro No I got you, what you want. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the data above no employees satisfy all the values for both for your comment *I want to get all employee_ids say, who have both emp_qualifctn_type (27 , 29) and both qualification_value (62,50)*.

For example for 2, the first rows has a match on both emp_qualifctn_type and qualification_value, but the 2nd row only matches on emp_qualifctn_type  while the 3rd only matches on qualification_value. So 2 does not have a match on all of them.

To get what you want I think you need to match on one OR the other rather than AND, and then you can check the counts:-

```
SELECT employee_id 
FROM  `otc_employee_qualifications` 
WHERE  (`emp_qualifctn_type` IN (27,  29)
OR  `qualification_value` IN (50, 62))
AND  `qualification_mark` >=  '10'
GROUP BY  `employee_id` 
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT  `emp_qualifctn_type` ) =  2
AND  COUNT( DISTINCT  `qualification_value` ) =  2
```